# Can you have nested asynchronous contexts?

Tags: java, asynchronous, servlets, jakarta-ee, blocking

So if [`AsyncContext::complete`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/AsyncContext.html#complete--) *closes* the response and I need to write the response within the asynchronous context, how do I implement a multi-step response in which *some* steps are blocking with non-blocking sections in-between them?

Comment: It's unclear what problem you perceive here.    You may write to the response as many times as you like, at whatever timing you like, within the scope of one asynchronous context.  You may flush any such output.  When you're completely done with all servicing of a request being handled in a given asynchronous context. if ever you are, you invoke its `complete()` method to so indicate.

Comment: I guess you would get a logically-nested asynchronous context by, while processing a request asynchronously, obtaining a `RequestDispatcher` and using it to `include()` a resource that itself performs asynchronous processing.  I don't presently see the utility of seeking out such a situation specifically, however.

Comment: @JohnBollinger As you say, I can write "as many times I like, at whatever timing I like WITHIN THE SCOPE OF ONE asynchronous context". So what if I have multiple? Starting an asynchronous context will move execution to a new thread and free the current one. What if I then need to do that again? I can't `complete` the operation I just finished because that would close the response. Do I just leave it open? What happens to the response I wrote in the other context that I did not close, then?

Comment: I think your conceptualization of an asynchronous context is serving you poorly.  A request being handled asynchronously is "asynchronous" specifically with respect to the original request handling method of the servlet to which it was initially dispatched.  It is not moved automatically to some other thread.  Obtaining an `AsyncContext` is what allows *you* to arrange for processing in another thread, or multiple other threads, or whatever, and ultimately to indicate when processing is complete.

Comment: @JohnBollinger it's not moved? [Oracle's jave ee tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/servlets012.htm#BEIGCFDF), seems to disagree on this: "If a servlet or a filter reaches a potentially blocking operation when processing a request, it can assign the operation to an asynchronous execution context and return the thread associated with the request immediately to the container without generating a response. The blocking operation completes in the asynchronous execution context in a different thread, which can generate a response or dispatch the request to another servlet."

Comment: @JohnBollinger what am I misunderstanding?

Comment: That text from the JavaEE tutorial is talking *generally* about a way you can write servlets.  It does not say or mean that creating an async context automatically does anything other than "put[ing] the request into asynchronous mode and ensur[ing] that the response is not committed after exiting the service method," as it describes soon after.  An `AsyncContext` is for the asynchronous work you implement, running in the thread you arrange for it, to interact with the container outside the context provided by a servlet's request-handling method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be operating under a misapprehension about the nature of an `AsyncContext` and the semantics of `ServletRequest::startAsync`.  This method (re)initializes an `AsyncContext` for the request and associated response, creating one first if necessary, and associates it with the request / response pair.  This puts the request into asynchronous mode, ***which, at its core, means nothing more than that the container will not consider request processing complete until the provided context's `complete()` method is invoked***.

In particular, creating an async context does not create any threads or assign the associated request to a different thread, and the methods of an `AsyncContext` run on the thread that invokes them (though that's kinda a technicality for `AsyncContext::start`).  The context is primarily an object for whatever asynchronous code you provide to use for interacting with the container, which it otherwise could not safely do.  To actually perform processing on some other thread, *you* need to arrange for that thread to exist, and for the work to be assigned to it.  `AsyncContext::start` is a convenient way to do that, but not the only way.

With respect specifically to

> how do I implement a multi-step response in which some steps are blocking with non-blocking sections in-between them?

, the basic answer is "however you want".  The `AsyncContext` neither hinders nor particularly helps you because it's about communication with the container, not about workflow.  In particular, I see no need or special use for nested `AsyncContext`s.

I think you're describing a processing pipeline with certain, limited parallelization.  You might implement that, say, by running the overall workflow -- all the "blocking" steps, I guess -- in a thread launched via `AsyncContext::start`, and dispatching the other work to a thread pool, in whatever units make sense.  Do be aware, however, that the request and response objects are not thread-safe.  Ideally, then, the primary thread will extract all the needed data from the request, and perform all needed writes to the response.

Alternatively, maybe you use the regular request processing thread for the main workflow, dispatch pieces of work to a thread pool as appropriate, and skip the `AsyncContext` bit altogether.  It is not necessary in any absolute sense to use an `AsyncContext` to perform asynchronous computations in a web application -- it's purpose and the processing models it is designed to support are rather a lot more specific.